# Java generics override static methods workaround

Tags: java, generics, static, polymorphism, overriding

I'm working on a project that requires me to serialize and deserialize generic objects. The way I'm going about this, is defining an abstract class `Serializer` that implements a `toBytes()` and a static `fromBytes()`. All is well with this approach, as I can pass an object instance to a generic class `Foo` that expects a `Serializer` subclass, and I can ensure the object knows how to serialize and deserialize itself.

Now my question. Java serialization kinda sucks. I have multiple implementations I'd like to try swapping in and out, and ultimately I'd like the user to be able to decide the format. How would I go about changing the implementation details of `Serializer`? I know I can't override static methods, so how would I do this without decoupling `Foo` and `Serializer` and not being able to ensure my generic object has the appropriate `toBytes()` and `fromBytes()` method in `Foo`?

Here is code if anyone is confused:

```
public abstract class Serializer {
    public static Serializer fromBytes(byte[] bytes) {
        ...
    }

    public byte[] toBytes() {
        ...
    }
}

public class Foo<T extends Serializer> {
    private T t;
    public Foo(T t) {
        this.t = t;
    }

    public void foo() {
        t.toBytes(); //this will polymorph into the correct call because it's called on the object instance and not the Serializer class
    }

    public void bar(byte[] bytes) {
        T.fromBytes(bytes); // I'd like to be able to override this method so I can use different implementations
    }
}
```

Comment: Do fromBytes method have to be static?

Comment: @eitann, no, it does not. However I'd like to avoid instantiating a new object to call a deserialize method to then return a different instance entirely. I've considered a constructor that deserializes, but I'd be cloning the object which I'd like to avoid. I have the bytes of the object, I'd simply like an abstract way of statically turning it into a reference, hopefully without any hackery.

Comment: You are saying that you don't want to create instance for the serializer, and use a static behavior though still give it a flexible behavior, this is not possible. It's not a bad thing to create an instance at the beginning of the program, with a factory that decides which behavior to use (which instance), and then pass it as a parameter to the method.  Also its really not a good thing to put logic in a constructor.

Comment: @eitann, I understand it's not possible I was looking for a design pattern that fit my needs. I was saying I didn't want to do something like `Serializer s = new ConcreteSerializer().fromBytes(bytes)` to achieve polymorphic deserialization calls. You're saying decoupling the serializing logic from the item to be serialized? I was hoping to avoid that so I could keep the serialization logic in the object itself, but I guess I'll have to make a compromise somewhere.

Comment: What about a static class that get a serializer and data as a parameter, like this: `SerializeOperator.serialize(serializer, bytes)`. The signature of the method is an interface of serializer and you pass him a concrete serializer.

Comment: I guess I could make `Serializer` a wrapper object, similar to what you suggested. Then instead of the object being a subclass of `Serializer`, `Serializer` simply has a reference to the object to be serialized and abstract methods for serializing and deserializing. Then I can still pass just a `Serializer` instance to `Foo` and not need `fromBytes()` to be static. I was hoping to keep the logic in the object itself though in case I needed to override for per object serialization, but this seems like potentially the cleanest to me.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is a good approach, but how about using Jackson library and serialize your object as a json node? for example:

```
@JsonTypeInfo(
          use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, 
          include = JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY, 
          property = "type")
        @JsonSubTypes({ 
          @Type(value = SoundFile.class, name = "sound"), 
          @Type(value = VideoFile.class, name = "video") 
        })
abstract class File{
    private String id;
    private String type;
    @JsonCreator
    public File(@JsonProperty("id") String id)
    {
        this.id=id;
    }
    public String getId() {return this.id;}
    public abstract String getType();
}

class SoundFile extends File{

    @JsonCreator
    public SoundFile(@JsonProperty("id") String id) {
        super(id);
    }

    @Override
    public String getType() {
        return "sound";
    }


}

class VideoFile extends File{

    @JsonCreator
    public VideoFile(@JsonProperty("id") String id) {
        super(id);
    }

    @Override
    public String getType() {
        return "video";
    }

}

public class GenericApp {



    public static void main(String[] args) {
    ObjectMapper om = new ObjectMapper();

    List<File> files = Arrays.asList(new VideoFile("1"),new SoundFile("2"));

    //serialize
    List<byte[]> fileSerialized = files.stream().map(file->{
        try {
        return om.writeValueAsBytes(file);
        }catch(Exception e) {return null;}
    }).collect(Collectors.toList());

    //de-serialize
    List<File> filesDeSerialized = fileSerialized.stream().map(bytes ->{
        try {
            return om.readValue(bytes, File.class);
        }
        catch(Exception e) {return null;}
    }).collect(Collectors.toList());

    filesDeSerialized.stream().forEach(file->{
        System.out.println("id :"+file.getId()+" - "+file.getClass());
    });

    }

}
```

this would properly deserialize these objects and print:

```
id :1 - class com.dsncode.stackoverflow.VideoFile
id :2 - class com.dsncode.stackoverflow.SoundFile
```

however, you should define a @JsonTypeInfo and a @JsonSubType for all your sub-classes of your Generic Type. Because, by indicating this field, you will indicate to Jackson deserializer, which class should create for your generic type.

Comment: I'm trying to make my code flexible enough to do either binary or json serialization at runtime.

Comment: @MeetTitan then you can use om.writeValueAsBytes(file) for bytes[] and om.writeValueAsString for json string and om.valueToTree(file) for JsonObject. just replace, implement & inject the map Function in realtime accordingly

Comment: I'm trying to change the underlying byte representation (some implementations may compress better or serialize faster, so I want it to be extendable), not change to a different concrete implementation. I have code that will serialize using `ObjectOutputStream`, Json, and xml. I'd like to be able to change which one I'm using and still pass only a `Serializer` to my `Foo` class, not hardcode an implementation.